# Swift: Difference between Locale.current & Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)

Tags: swift, locale

What is the difference between Locale.current & Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)?

Comment: It should be the same, but when you do `Locale.current.identifier`, you start by doing ` Locale.current`, so you are "doing it twice".

Comment: @Larme Interestingly, they are not equal according to `==`, and `Locale.current.description` also has the word "current" in it, but a `Locale` created from an identifier doesn't, so I wonder where the difference is...

Answer (score 4):

The former will reflect the current device settings (including any customizations). The latter will instantiate a new instance, reflecting the default property values for the current locale.